# How to run a sudo command without a password where the command can be altered?

Tags: command-line, sudo, password

I know this question gets asked a lot but my situation is a little different. I am using Qt and the user has the ability to change timezones. Therefore, the following commands need to be used (America/Los_Anegles can change):

```
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

I would like to run these commands without a password. I read that you could write the following in  /etc/sudoers :

```
user = (root) NOPASSWD: command
```

where command is something like:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

However, the command has to be specific and as I stated before, America/Los_Angeles could potentially change. Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: You create a script that the user cannot edit. And then update the script as needed. How is the `America/Los_Angeles` expected to change?

Comment: that was my question basically. The America/Los_Angeles was just an example. In other words, sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/{unknown} /etc/localtime

Comment: Use `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/* /etc/localtime` for the `command` part.

Comment: I added the following and it keeps telling there is a syntax error...

myusername ALL =(ALL) NOPASSWD: ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/* /etc/localtime

Comment: My bad, you need to provide the full path for `ls`: `myusername ALL =(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ls -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/* /etc/localtime`